# Mailbox unavailable

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient

I got the following error trying send email with the following code, can anyone please correct me if am wrong?

```
public async static Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
{
    try
    {
        var _email = "myemail@hotmail.com";
        var epass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mypassword"];
        var _dispName = "Blog";
        MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
        myMessage.To.Add(email);
        myMessage.From = new MailAddress(_email, _dispName);
        myMessage.Subject = subject;
        myMessage.Body = message;
        myMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
        {
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_email, epass);
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.SendCompleted += (s, e) => { smtp.Dispose(); };
            await smtp.SendMailAsync(myMessage);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

The server response was:

```
 5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated
```

Comment: Try to change the port specific to hotmail `Hotmail SMTP port: 25 or 465`

Comment: when i tried 25 or 465, i got error saying "server does not support secure connection".

Comment: Please change this to false `smtp.EnableSsl = true;` :D